# Row data distributed into multiple rows on a separate sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

I have a fuel consumption log, with vehicle id's in column 'C' and fuel consumed and distance traveled for different dates as the headers.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TylL5.png)

I have made multiple sheets based on the vehicle id's  with Dates under column 'A' and rest of the headers being - [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W9Qu.png).

From the first sheet, I need to bring in KM and fuel consumed date-wise to the second sheet and similarly to other 764 sheets.

Comment: I think a little more information would be useful. For starters what is your question? In other words, what do you want to accomplish, what have you tried and how does it fail to meet expectations?

Comment: In the main sheet, i have date and below date two fields/headers (KM & Fuel), i have such data across columns from 1/12 to 31/12.

Comment: I have made multiple sheets based on the vehicle id (in total 764 sheets) and each sheet now has the dates in a single column and i want KM & Fuel for each date from the main sheet...

Comment: Please take the time to read [this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) you also want to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1417283/edit) instead of adding info in comments. From what you say `='Sheet1'A1` is the formula you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:
- your main sheet is called "Main Sheet",
- your 764 sheets are called exactly like your vehicle ids,
you could use the following formulas.

For the distance column:

```
=INDEX('Main Sheet'!$1:$1048576,
  MATCH(MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,255),'Main Sheet'!$C:$C,0),
  MATCH($A2,'Main Sheet'!$1:$1,0))
```

For the fuel column:

```
=INDEX('Main Sheet'!$1:$1048576,
  MATCH(MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,255),'Main Sheet'!$C:$C,0),
  MATCH($A2,'Main Sheet'!$1:$1,0)+1)
```

In every formula you have 3 references to "Main Sheet", so just change that to your real sheet name. Also, if you use Excel 2003 or earlier, you will have to change the row number on the first line from `$1:$1048576` to `$1:$65536`.

For the first vehicle id sheet I get this:
[image: index match cell filename]

Comment: Was the answer helpful?